# To display the names of all students who have secured more than 50 in all subjects that they have appeared in

Tags: oracle

Write a query to display the names of all students who have secured more than 50 in all subjects that they have appeared in, ordered by student name in ascending order.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOsPh.png)

I have used this below query but didn't getting desired result as it is not comparing the result by grouping the student_id as whole.
Can anyone suggest any changes in query please.

```
select distinct student_name from student s join mark m on
s.student_id = m.student_id join subject sb
on m.subject_id = sb.subject_id
where m.value IN 
(select value from mark m1 join student s1
on m1.student_id = s1.student_id join subject sb1
on m1.subject_id = sb1.subject_id
where value > 50 group by s1.student_id,m1.value, sb1.subject_id)
order by 1;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need such a complex subquery. All you need to do is just find out the minimum marks for a student ([INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) ensures that only those subjects are considered, which have been attempted by the student).

Do a simple [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) between student and marks table on student_id. We do a [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) on the `student_id` and get `minimum_marks` for each student. If the `minimum_marks` > 50, it means that the student has > 50 marks in all the subjects. 
Try the following, this will work in **MySQL** (as per the Original tag by OP):

```
SELECT s.student_name, MIN(m.value) AS minimum_marks 
FROM student s 
JOIN mark m ON s.student_id = m.student_id 
GROUP BY s1.student_id 
HAVING minimum_marks > 50 
ORDER BY s.student_name ASC
```

**Edit** As per Oracle (since OP edited later), [aliased fields/expressions are not allowed](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2379402) in the `HAVING` clause. Revised query would look like:

```
SELECT s.student_name, MIN(m.value) AS minimum_marks 
FROM student s 
JOIN mark m ON s.student_id = m.student_id 
GROUP BY s1.student_id 
HAVING MIN(m.value) > 50 
ORDER BY s.student_name ASC
```

Comment: This query is not working it is showing error as "Invalid identifier" for minimum_marks at "having minimum_marks > 50".

Comment: @RishikaMittal are you sure that you are using MySQL ? It seems like you are using Oracle SQL

Comment: I am so sorry I wrongly mentioned the tag I will correct the tag but can you still help me with the Oracle SQL query

Comment: @RishikaMittal yes I have edited. Pls check. Let me know if it still does not work. if it works, you can accept the answer and upvote as well :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select student_name
from student join mark using (student_id)
group by student_name
having min(value) > 50
order by student_name;
```

A sub-query should be avoided if possible. So by having check if the minimum marks scored by a student is greater than 50 , we can say that he has scored more than 50 in all his subjects.

Answer (score 1):

```
select student_name from student where student_id in
(select student_id 
    from (select student_id ,min(value) from mark group by student_id having min(value)>50)
)
order by student_name;
```

As it is simple by making subquery as shown above.

**1**.Extract min value that is greater than 50 and create a table and then compare it from the student table.

**2**.without using any Join operation

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct student_name from student,mark
where student.student_id = mark.student_id
having min(value) > 50
group by student_name
order by student_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_name
from student s inner join mark m
on s.student_id= m.student_id
having min(m.value)>50
group by student_name
order by student_name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.student _name from student s join mark m 
on s.student_id = m.student_id
group by s.student_name
having min(m.value) > 50
order by s.student_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_name from student
where student_id in (select student_id from mark group by student_id having min(value) > 50)
order by student_name;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
MySQL> select studentid, name,mark from students where mark>20;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: :-) At first I had the impression that you are asking for help with a broken piece of code. Luckily I realised in time that you probably do attempt to answer....

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT s.student_name
FROM student s
WHERE s.student_id NOT IN (
    SELECT m.student_id
    FROM mark m
  where m.student_id = s.student_id
    and m.value <= 50
)
ORDER BY s.student_name ASC;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?